# NSJSONSerialization does not return data, but its showing data in json viewer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

`NSJSONSerialization` returns null when i try to implement a particular api from the server, but other api's from the server works fine , when i tried the api in web it returns data of json type , and i have checked it in json viewer also , and it worked fine , `NSData` also returns some data, can Anyone help me get through it ?

```
NSString *urlString = @"url";        
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
_dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

if(error != nil){

    NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", error);
    return;
}
```

I have tried the above written code.

---**Edited**-----
Since it was a issue from server side as server was sending an Invalid Character along with response, In json validator it was passing but not in a actual Program , Hence closing the question.

Comment: thanks guys for your useful answers. actually the problem was with the server , they have added an invalid character in the json.

Comment: I hav checked it using `[NSJSONSerialization isValidJson]` which tells weather the json returned is a valid one or not.

Comment: What error is being returned??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was not in the code but in the server data coming as response.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is of **Escape Sequences** in your URL and you are not escaping them. You have to escape those sequences properly.

```
NSString *urlString = @"url";        
NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

1. Take a Look at [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).
2. Check also the [Escape Sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387756/1603072).

**Try this :**

```
NSString *urlString = @"url";        
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: @vinay.bn : If your URL is working in browser and not working in xcode then it is the problem of escape sequences only. Check the Documentation also.

Comment: @vinay.bn: Take a look at my Update Section.

Comment: :the url doesn't contain any escape character.

Comment: @vinay.bn: Just use that code in Update and let me know if it's working or not.

Comment: `NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` Use this line to fetch the data and then `NSLog` it.

Comment: @vinay.bn: What was the result of that `NSLog` ?

Comment: I encoded the data and it returns the desired result, but not able to get form the NSJsonserialization class...

Comment: @vinay.bn: What's the result that you are getting ? Is it an Error Message ?

Comment: when i try to read the nsdata through encoding it returns result as i xpected, but not able to get it form nsjsonserialization

Comment: :is there a way to parse json data without using nsserialization, bcoz i am getting data correct but not able to parse it using nsjsonsserialization

Comment: @vinay.bn: That means your JSON Data is not in proper format.

Comment: I am getting NSdata and if I encode the data i will get the nsstring of values, to check weather its problem in server return format I have tried in `http://jsonviewer.stack.hu` website and it returns the value which i need inthe format of json,probably it might be the problem in NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: `NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];` Try this way. I think the problem is in initialization of your Dictionary.

Comment: @vinary.bn Would you please mark the answer as correct? It is only fair that you give Vin the reps since he helped a lot and you solved you issue due to his help, so I think it would be more than appropriate after more than a month...

Answer (score 1):

Make a `NSURLConnection` and request the `JSON` with `NSURLRequest` because I don't think the 'json' is an actual file that has content so you could use  `dataWithContentsOfURL:`

Comment: ya its get replaced by actual url , i tried switching that 0 into NSJSONReadingMutableContainers but same result.

Comment: Check the NSLog to see what you receive.

Comment: i tried the  NSlog option you have given, but it returns null, may i know what would be the reson , is it from server side or in my coding ?

Comment: I think you don't receive the NSData corectly , I think you should use NSURLConnnection and make a request to the server instead.

Comment: It'll be the `XML Code` representing the `Error Message`.

Comment: @Vin Yeah, I figured out later the page isn't static